# Qual Script SQL em Postgres para retornar as Functions de um Schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Qual Script SQL em Postgres para retornar as Functions de um Schema com seus parametros de entradas ?

Comment: Pessoal eu só coloquei dicar de como Obter essa informação, não é pergunta..  eu pesquiso muito e só acho no stack em ingles..e por isso estou colocando scripts mais simplificados para pessoas que estao aparendendo...  obrigado..  ** não é necessário negativar...** podem reparar que fui eu mesmo que respondi, caso não seja legal o que fiz posso excluir sem problemas, so quis ajudar

Comment: Aqui Gustavo a sua pergunta também tem problemas, igual a anterior, se quiser mude coloque um pergunta realmente.

Comment: OK, corrigindo....  Obrigado...

Comment: quero colocar mais perguntas assim com as respostas  mais simples possivel.  para os iniciantes entenderem melhor esses scripts...

Comment: Eu entendi Gustavo, o problema inicial era realmente suas perguntas e respostas sem um contexto, mas, tem claro um resposta boa. Sempre que fizer perguntas e responder tente enriquecer ao máximo

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    inf.routine_name, 
    par.data_type, 
    par.ordinal_position,
    par.parameter_name,
    par.parameter_mode
FROM 
    information_schema.routines inf
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     information_schema.parameters par ON inf.specific_name = par.specific_name
WHERE 
    inf.specific_schema='name_schema' and
    par.parameter_mode = 'IN'
ORDER BY 
    inf.routine_name, 
    par.ordinal_position;
```

ou
Mostra Funções não Ligadas a Triggers

```
SELECT 
    format('%I.%I(%s)', 
    ns.nspname, 
    p.proname, 
    pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid))
FROM 
    pg_proc p 
left outer JOIN 
    pg_namespace ns ON (p.pronamespace = ns.oid)
WHERE 
    ns.nspname = 'seu esquema' and
    p.proretset = true;
```